# Unable to fetch Azure VM's in Prometheus using Service discovery

Tags: azure, prometheus, monitoring, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm trying to monitor azure VM's in Grafana through Prometheus. I have update prometheus.yml using service discovery as azure_sd_configs. Node exporter is configured on all the VM's and is up and running. But this data is not reflecting in prometheus. I did lot of troubleshooting but couldn't get it. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you. Prometheus.yml file below. After applying the below configuration prometheus starts but the VM's are not reflected as such.

```
   global:
   scrape_interval: 10s

   scrape_configs:
   - job_name: 'prometheus_master'
     scrape_interval: 5s
     static_configs:
       - targets: ['localhost:9090']

   - job_name: 'azure-nodes'
     azure_sd_configs:
       - subscription_id: "SUB_ID"
         tenant_id: "tenant_ID"
         client_id: "Client_id"
         client_secret: "Secret"
         port: 9100


  remote_write:
  - url: "http://URL:9100/metrics"
    basic_auth:
      username: "****"
      password: "******"
```

Comment: Have you gotten this to work yet? I am working on setting up a similar environment

Comment: are you sure on `client_secret`, here you need to provide Client Secret 'Value', not the "Secret ID", in my case this was the issue